# Storing values from a cookie into an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I've looked through a million different websites and I can't seem to find an answer—is there a way to get info from a cookie and put it into an array? I've tried directly storing `$_COOKIE['name']` into an array, and that causes a server error. I've tried storing `$_COOKIE['name']` as a `$variable`, but when I print out the array, it literally just returns `$variable`. Any words of wisdom out there from someone who has done this successfully?

Code (other than the actual array code, the entire page works fine):

```
 $productarray = array("$_COOKIE['gatq']"=>'The Great Gatsby <img src="gatsby.jpg">',
                 "$_COOKIE['catcherq']"=>'Catcher in the Rye <img src="catcher.jpg">',
                  "$_COOKIE['wavesq']"=>'The Waves <img src="waves.jpg">',
                  "$_COOKIE['strangerq']"=>'The Stranger <img src="stranger.jpg">',
                  "$_COOKIE['ulyssesq']"=>'Ulysses <img src="ulysses.jpg">',
                  "$_COOKIE['prideq']"=>'Pride and Prejudice <img src="pride.jpg">',
                  "$_COOKIE['mockingbirdq']"=>'To Kill a Mockingbird <img src="mockingbird.jpg">',
                  "$_COOKIE['roadq']"=>'On the Road <img src="road.jpg">'
                  );

if ($_COOKIE['fname'] == NULL or $_COOKIE['lname'] == NULL or $_COOKIE['address'] == NULL or $_COOKIE['city'] == NULL or $_COOKIE['state'] == NULL or $_COOKIE['zip'] == NULL)
{echo "<script language='javascript'>
window.alert('You left some information on the personal info page! You will be redirected.');
    window.location.href='personal.php';</script>";
}

else
    {
        if ($_COOKIE['gatq'] == NULL &&
            $_COOKIE['catcherq'] == NULL &&
            $_COOKIE['wavesq'] == NULL &&
            $_COOKIE['strangerq'] == NULL &&
            $_COOKIE['ulyssesq'] == NULL &&
            $_COOKIE['prideq'] == NULL &&
            $_COOKIE['mockingbirdq'] == NULL &&
            $_COOKIE['roadq'] == NULL)

                {echo "<script language='javascript'>
                    window.alert('You don't have anything in your shopping cart! You will be redirected.');
                    window.location.href='inventory.php';</script>";
                }

                        else
                            {

                                asort($productarray);
                                foreach ($productarray as $book=>$info)
                                            {if ($book != NULL)
                                                    echo $book . "$info\n";
                                            }
                                echo $productarray;
                                echo "testing";


                            }

    }
?>
```

The error just says "server error," which is the same error I get anytime I have any kind of syntax error.

Comment: It should work the first way you tried, show your code.

Comment: And tell us what the error was.

Comment: What do you mean by "print out"?. You can't print out a cookie directly.=)

Comment: You should check the PHP error log on the server to see the detailed error. The problem is that you have a syntax error, so the script can't run.

Answer (score 2):

Variables aren't expanded inside single-quoted strings. Just use `$_COOKIE['name']` as the array key directly.

```
$productarray = array($_COOKIE['gatq']=>'The Great Gatsby <img src="gatsby.jpg">',
                  $_COOKIE['catcherq']=>'Catcher in the Rye <img src="catcher.jpg">',
                  $_COOKIE['wavesq']=>'The Waves <img src="waves.jpg">',
                  $_COOKIE['strangerq']=>'The Stranger <img src="stranger.jpg">',
                  $_COOKIE['ulyssesq']=>'Ulysses <img src="ulysses.jpg">',
                  $_COOKIE['prideq']=>'Pride and Prejudice <img src="pride.jpg">',
                  $_COOKIE['mockingbirdq']=>'To Kill a Mockingbird <img src="mockingbird.jpg">',
                  $_COOKIE['roadq']=>'On the Road <img src="road.jpg">'
                  );
```

I'm not sure what you're really trying to do here, though. Why would the values of cookies be the keys of an associative array? What's in `$_COOKIE['gatq']`, for instance?

I think what you really want is a 2-dimensional array:

```
$productarray = array(
                  array('quantity'=>$_COOKIE['gatq'], 'title'=>'The Great Gatsby <img src="gatsby.jpg">'),
                  array('quantity'=>$_COOKIE['catcherq'], 'title'=>'Catcher in the Rye <img src="catcher.jpg">'),
                  array('quantity'=>$_COOKIE['wavesq'], 'title'=>'The Waves <img src="waves.jpg">'),
                  array('quantity'=>$_COOKIE['strangerq'], 'title'=>'The Stranger <img src="stranger.jpg">'),
                  array('quantity'=>$_COOKIE['ulyssesq'], 'title'=>'Ulysses <img src="ulysses.jpg">'),
                  array('quantity'=>$_COOKIE['prideq'], 'title'=>'Pride and Prejudice <img src="pride.jpg">'),
                  array('quantity'=>$_COOKIE['mockingbirdq'], 'title'=>'To Kill a Mockingbird <img src="mockingbird.jpg">'),
                  array('quantity'=>$_COOKIE['roadq'], 'title'=>'On the Road <img src="road.jpg">')
                  );
```

To display this in quantity order, you can use `usort()` with a function that compares `$element['quantity']`.

Comment: Huh, that's what I tried the first time around and it didn't work, but I just tried it again and it solved the problem! Thanks! Maybe I had a simpler syntax mistake going on earlier that I didn't notice. In any case, the cookies store user-inputted data from a form on a separate page, i.e. the quantity of how many books they'd like to order. So on this page, I was wanting to reflect back those quantities, but in descending order, which called for an array. We all have our reasons for what we're trying to do. But thank you so much!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use quantities as the keys of an associative array, since they aren't unique and don't identify anything.

Comment: See my updated answer for what I think you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

[$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) is already an array.

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

You would handle it like any other array.

```
if(!empty($_COOKIE['catcherq'])){
  $catcherq = $_COOKIE['catcherq'];
  echo $catcherq; 
}

foreach($_COOKIE as $key=>$value){
  echo ("$key:$value\n");
  ${$key}=$value;
}
```